# How do you embed a joint_state_publisher_gui window into rviz

Tags: rviz, joint-state-publisher

Right now I have a lot of joint_state_publisher_gui windows and I want to have them integrated into a custom panel in RViz2. I know RViz is really customizable but I was wondering if there is an easy way to do this/something already done like this I can reference? Thanks!